# What is a programmable power-up sequencer?

Tags: microcontroller, texas-instruments, power-sequencing

What is a programmable power-up sequencer ?
How to use it in a PMIC to power AM335x TI microprocessor ?

Comment: I'm just wondering, if you don't know what it is why do you want to use one?

Comment: Using reset and power supply sequencers is a subject in its own right. TI provides reference designs for this series which you should study *before* trying to do your own design (*especially* if you have never designed with sequencers before). See https://www.ti.com/reference-designs/index.html#search?keyword=am335x&applid=120&famid=3387,1875

Comment: What is the difference between an analog sequencer and a digital sequencer ?

Answer (score 4):

A programmable power-up sequencer is a chip that turns all supply voltages on (and off) in a specific order and with specific time delays that are necessary for the system to avoid malfunction and damage from getting powered in wrong order. How to use it will depend on the specific requirements for the powered system.

Comment: What is the difference between an analog sequencer and a digital sequencer ?